# Continue asking user for input until condition is met in two way process

Tags: c, pipe, fork, exit

I continue to ask for user input until a negative number is entered. One user enters a positive number, the parent reads it and passes the input to the child. The child replies back with square root of input, then the parent displays it and asks for next input until user inputs negative number. I got the program to exit if it is a negative number but am struggling with the `while` loop to keep the program going if a positive number.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int x;
    printf("Enter an Integer (-ve to quit): ");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    
    while (x < 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    int fd[2];
    if (pipe(fd) == -1) {
        printf("An error occurred with opening the pipe\n");
        return 1;
    }
    
    int id = fork();
    if (id == -1) {
        printf("An error occurred with fork\n");
        return 2;
    }
    
    if (id == 0) {
        // Child process
        close(fd[0]);
     
        if (write(fd[1], &x, sizeof(int)) == -1) {
            printf("An error occurred with writing to the pipe\n");
            return 3;
        }
        close(fd[1]);
    } else {
        // Parent process
        close(fd[1]);
        int y;
        while (1) {
            if (read(fd[0], &y, sizeof(int)) == -1) {
                printf("An error occurred with reading from the pipe\n");
                return 4;
            } else {
                printf("Child Process: I received  %d\n", y);
                y *= y;
                printf("Parent Process: I received %d\n", y);
                close(fd[0]);
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: ```while (x < 0){
    return 0;``` --> why is this in a loop?

Comment: *"The child process then squares the user input, and sends it back to the parent to print to the screen."* ---> But the child process is not doing that. The parent is.

Comment: *"I continue to ask for user input until a negative number is entered."* ---> You need a loop.

Comment: @BearB – 
… _a child process that passes the user input to child process_?

Comment: Sorry that did not make sense. I edited my post. I think its time to take a break. I have been working on this for days.  I have not learned C, but am programming it for assignments as requested.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, communication is bidirectional, so you need to have two pipes: one from parent to child and another backward. The structures you get back from pipe() each hold one fd to read from and the other to write to.

After establishing these pipes, the spawn is needed and parent and child have to go into their loops:

- child to first read from one pipe, then write result to the other
- parent to scan user input, then write it to one pipe and read the result from the other

In both loops, we break upon finding a negative number.
For parent we leave before expecting a result to be read (as child will not send it) while for child we quit before sending an (unwanted) result back to parent, which may already have kills it side of the pipe resulting in error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    int fd_child_to_parent[2];
    int fd_parent_to_child[2];
    if (pipe(fd_child_to_parent) == -1) {
        printf("An error occurred with opening the pipe\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (pipe(fd_parent_to_child) == -1) {
        printf("An error occurred with opening the pipe\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int id = fork();

    switch (id) {
        case 0:     // child
                close(fd_parent_to_child[1]);   // in child close write socket of p2c
                close(fd_child_to_parent[0]);   // and close read socket of c2p
                while (true) {
                    int x_child;
                    if (read(fd_parent_to_child[0], &x_child, sizeof(int)) == -1) {
                        printf("An error occurred while reading from parent\n");
                        return 2;
                    }
                    printf("Child Process: I received  %d\n", x_child);
                    if (x_child>=0) {
                        x_child*=x_child;
                        if (write(fd_child_to_parent[1], &x_child, sizeof(int)) == -1) {
                            printf("An error occurred while sending to parent\n");
                            return 3;
                        }
                        printf("Child Process: I have sent back %d\n", x_child);
                    } else {
                        printf("Child leaving ...\n");
                        // clean up the rest;
                        close(fd_parent_to_child[0]);
                        close(fd_child_to_parent[1]);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                break;
        case -1:    // error in forking
                printf("An error occurred while fork()ing\n");
                return 2;
                break;
        default:    // parent
                close(fd_parent_to_child[0]);   // in parent close read end of p2c
                close(fd_child_to_parent[1]);   // and write end of c2p
                while (true) {
                    int x_parent;
                    printf("Enter an Integer (any negative number to quit): ");
                    scanf("%d", &x_parent);
                    if (write(fd_parent_to_child[1], &x_parent, sizeof(int)) == -1) {
                        printf("An error occurred while sending to child\n");
                        return 4;
                    }
                    printf("Parent Process: I just sent %d\n", x_parent);
                    if (x_parent>=0) {  // communicate to child
                        if (read(fd_child_to_parent[0], &x_parent, sizeof(int)) == -1) {
                            printf("An error occurred while reading from child\n");
                            return 5;
                        }
                        printf("Parent Process: I received %d\n", x_parent);
                    } else {    // parent to leave infinite loop
                        printf("Parent leaving ...\n");
                        // clean up the rest;
                        close(fd_parent_to_child[1]);
                        close(fd_child_to_parent[0]);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ... there may still be unused includes ... didn't care for them

Comment: Thank you so much, I have been struggling with the concept.